# HTML/CSS Background feature how can i do this

Tags: html, css

i've been trying to find the name of this but i have no clue on how is this called and made.
I have been coding a html website and i wanted to do some experimenting with the background that there is Content on a white background(the white background is small just to cover the content not a main background) and behind it, is the background image. 
Check steam profile backgrounds everything is on the blue/black background and the games bgs are behind.

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Where's your coding attempt? Why should we check something if you could provide us a simple screenshot or at least a link?

Comment: I do not have a problem with the code. I want to know what this feature is called and then i'll post any code problems i have, i need a tutorials cause im very very new to those languages

Comment: do you have any drawing, any visual example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think to have understood your questione, in css make the body, or a background DIV height and width :100% than  set the background-image: imagepath;
 Now your should have the background.
than create a div, in CSS make it position: relative; height and width the size do your preferenze than to have it centered use matgin:auto; and to have only the background of the div look semi trasparente use a background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.8)
I hope to have answered your question.

PS if your need to get started try Code accademy.

Comment: Imma test it right now and inform you right after im done! Thanks for helping anyways!!!!